# Using asp.net postback inside a php page

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, postback

i have a `php` page (from Wordpress) who loads inside of it an `asp.net` page.

The inside page have some asp.net controls so every time i click something it **auto-postback** itself reloading the entire page in a totally **messed** up url.

I load the asp.net using jquery's `load()` function and i need to trigger some function inside of this page.

Now, when you press a asp button the page call a postback function, the new page read the post value and execute what needs to be executed.
In my case the post message is sent to wordpress who totally ignore it.
I need to forward this post data to my new page? Or i'm in a totally wrong way?
I'd like to don't use iFrames, there is another solution?

Answer (score 1):

i could only assume the asp.net is outside of the wordpress framework. Then it seems you are trying to communicate with the wordpress functions using php. If this is the case you can enable the wordpress frame work for a page out side of wordpress with this

require_once( dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-load.php' );

Doing that will include wordpress functions so you can utilize the built in API.